# Cannot display debug info from @Ignore

Tags: java, netbeans, junit, junit4

I tested to display some debug info using the @Ignore annotation:

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;

@Ignore(value = "Test for Zones is not yet finished")
```

But when I build the project using Netbeans I don't get any message 'Test for Zones is not yet finished'. I use Junit 4.11. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans doesn't seem to handle `@Ignore` very well, there is even an [open bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=186276) for that issue. My installation (v. 7.0.1) only lists executed tests, if completely ignores the `@Ignore`d ones (as if they didn't exist).

But even then, I don't think the annotation's `value` is required to be printed in the report. Eclipse and Maven (CLI) only include total number of tests executed/failed/ignored.
According to [@Ignore javadocs](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html):

> Native JUnit 4 test runners should report the number of ignored tests (...)

So your problem is more of a "feature request" than "a bug".